# how I set labels by the line type and by the point type?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I have this graph with 8 lines. This graph contains the lines of Wordcount, webdatascan, and monsterquery applications, and it contains in the version original, round-robin, and medusa.

The applications are represented by the line. You can see that all the wordcount examples have the same black line. All the webdatascan examples have the red dashed line. And, all the monsterquery examples have the dotted yellow line.

And for the versions, all the original versions have a circle in the points, the Round-robin versions have an "x", and the medusa versions have a star.

I want to separate the labels by its name and version (or by its line and point type), so that, in the end, I just have 3 labels with the lines (and without the pointtype) for wordcount, webdatascan, monsterquery. And I have another label with just the pointtype for round-robin, wordcount, and webdatascan.

how can I have a label just for the line type, and another label for the point type in gnuplot?

[image: My graph]

Comment: You could plot points and lines separately and give them the respective labels. But I'm not sure if then the  meaning of each item becomes clear (which color do the points get?)